# How to send email containing table data to a recipient each time a server table loads transferred data?

Tags: php, mysql, server, email

How can I send an email each time my second table in DB updates? Currently using phpMYadmin and transferring data from table1 to table2 on a weekly basis. Each time table1 transfers data to table2 I want the data in table2 to be sent to an email recipient. For the transfer to work properly I'm using MySQL event scheduler, and I would think/hope I could use the same service (setting up an event) to send the email, but I can't find anything on the subject.

Anyone out there who can point me in the right direction? Preferably links or even better -exact code and instructions on where to insert it.

Comment: You can use the plugin [`sys_exec()`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme) to execute any system command from inside mysql (and your event), or you could do it the other way round and use a cronjob to start both your weekly transfer and your program that sends the email or a combination of both (a cronjob that runs 30 minutes after your event, or the event sets a field that the cronjob regularly checks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually set up an email service through the command line connected to the server, while configuring a crontab to schedule a php-file which ran the php-mail-send function.